# More efficient algorithm to count attacks in N-queens?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, n-queens

I'm working on a DFS based solution to the N-queens problem.

I store the board state as an int[N] array representing the vertical placements of queens in each column (eg. placement of the queens diagonally down a 6x6 board would be state = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }), where -1 represents "no queen in this column".

My current algorithm for counting the queen attacks in a given state configuration has complexity of O(n^2):

```
function count_attacks(state)

    attack_count = 0

    for each column index c1
      if state[c1] == -1 continue

      for each column index c2 further along than c1
        if state[c2] == -1 continue

        // Lined up horizontally?
        if state[c1] == state[c2] attack_count++    

        // Lined up diagonally?
        else if (c2 - c1) == abs(state[c2] - state[c1]) attack_count++   

       // No need to check lined up vertically as impossible with this state representation

    return attack_count;
```

The O(N^2) kills performance when solving for say N=500+.

Is it possible to do better than O(N^2) for counting attacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define arrays

```
rows, columns, left_diagonals, right_diagonals
```

which count respectively the number of queens in the `i`-th row, column, left diagonal (all `x` and `y` such that `x-y=c` for some `c`), right diagonal (all `x` and `y` such that `x+y=c` for some `c`). The algorithm would then be:

```
Intialize rows, columns, left_diagonals, right_diagonals with zero values
attacks = 0
for queen in queens
    attacks += rows[queen.row];
    attacks += columns[queen.column];
    attacks += left_diagonals[queen.left_diagonal];
    attacks += right_diagonals[queen.right_diagonal];
    rows[queen.row]++;
    columns[queen.column]++;
    left_diagonals[queen.left_diagonal]++;
    right_diagonals[queen.right_diagonal]++;
```

However, for solving the `N` queen problem you don't need to check the number of attacks. You just need to check if an attack exists.

Also, if you are looking for a single solution of the problem there is a [very efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-conflicts_algorithm#Example).

Comment: Good observation about lack of need to count attacks

Comment: Yes great observation, and this could be a massive improvement with DFS. One caveat though, that if you plan to use heuristics then you'll likely need the full attack count.